# Finding files that are *not* hard links via a shell script

Tags: shell, hardlink

Given a directory, how do I find all files within it (and any sub-directories) that are *not* hard-linked files? Or more specifically, that are not hard-linked files with more than one reference?

Basically I want to scan a folder and return a list of *unique* files within that directory, including directories and symbolic links (not their targets). If possible, it'd be nice to also ignore hard-linked directories on file-systems that support them (such as HFS+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard-linked files have the same inode. You can use [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat) to print the inode and the filename, and use `awk` to print the file only for the first time that inode appears:

```
stat -c '%i %n' *csv | awk '!seen[$1]++' | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is the solution I'm going with with some differences; I'm getting the inode number for a file in one directory, and comparing with the corresponding file in a previous directory, if they match then I skip it, otherwise it isn't linked. This works for hard-linked directories as well (on supported file-systems).

Answer (score 25):

`find` has an option that should be useful:

```
find . -type f -links 1 -print
```

Files that are hard linked by definition have a link count of 2 or greater, so this will show all files that have no other links to them.

Comment: `-type f` excludes symlinks, directories, and several other things. The OP specifically wants to include directories and symlinks. Directories have at least two hard links (one from the parent, plus the directory's own `.` link), plus one for each subdirectory's `..`.

Comment: The `-type f` can be left out, in that case. However, the first and second paragraph of the question seem to disagree on that requirement. Typically, directories and symlinks won't have hard links to them anyway (although there are a couple of file system types where that's less true than others).

Comment: Directories always have hard links. They can have hard links other than the usual ones (from the parent directory, `.` from the directory itself, and `..` from child directories) on *some* systems; the OP specifically mentioned that. And you can have hard links to symlinks: `touch file; ln -s symlink file; ln hardlink symlink` will make `hardlink` a symbolic link to `file`, with the same inode number as `symlink`.

Comment: Right - I mean't "typically" in the sense that it's not a particularly common practice to hard link sym links (and any scenario I can come up with off the top of my head where that's actually useful is pretty contrived). And, yes, directories use the hard link count for a slightly different purpose - you can't actually usually do `ln dir1 dir2`, though...

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you know, *all* files have at least one hard link (in the parent directory).

To answer the question in your first paragraph (finding files that don't have *additional* hardlinks), you'll need to distinguish between directories and everything else. Assuming you have GNU Coreutils, you can use:

```
stat '%h' filename
```

to determine the number of hard links for a given file name.  Otherwise you can parse the output of `ls -ld filename` -- which should work, but `ls` output isn't really meant to be machine-readable.

For anything other than a directory, if the number of links is greater than 1, there's a hard link to it somewhere.

A directory, on the other hand, will always have the usual one link from its parent, plus one for its own `.` entry, plus one for the `..` entry of *each* of its immediate subdirectories. So you'll have to determine how many links it would have in the absence of any additional hard links, and compare that to the number it actually has.

You can avoid doing this if you happen to know that you're on a system that forbids hard links to directories. (I'm not sure whether that restriction is typically imposed by the OS or by each filesystem.)

But that doesn't solve the problem in your second paragraph, creating a list of unique files within a directory. Knowing that the plain file `foo` has a link count greater than 1 *doesn't* tell you whether it's unique in the current directory; the other hard links could be in different directories (they merely have to be in the same filesystem).

To do that, you can do something like:

```
stat -c '%i %n' *
```

which prints the inode number and name for each file in the current directory.  You can then filter out duplicate inode numbers to get unique entries.  This is basically what [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283363/827263) says.  Of course `*` doesn't actually match *everything* in the current directory; it skips files whose names start with `.`, and it can cause problems if some files have special characters (like space) in their names. That may not matter to you, but if it does (assuming GNU find):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c '%i %n'
```

(That will still cause problems if any file names contain newline characters, which is actually legal.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! If it helps, what I'm actually trying to do is recurse a Time Machine backup directory on OS X, and want to filter out everything that is just a link to a previous backup. For files this should mean that anything with only 1 link is sufficient, but for directories I'm probably going to have to use something more tricky then.

Comment: find knows about inode numbers and can print them directly, without the need to pipe into xargs: find . -maxdepth 1 -printf "%i %p\n"

Answer (score 1):

So all what you want is whatever file/link/dir/block/pipe/... but with different inode ? 
Then it's easy, list them with inode, do a numeric sort and finally only print the one with different inode numbers ... and remind find has a lot of options to restrict the output if you want to filter

find /PATH_to_SEARCH -ls | sort -n | awk '!seen[$1]++'